# Trouble making Marquee text continous in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

I'm trying to make my marquee text continuous, but can't figure out how too. This is what I've right now in my HTML:

```css
.marquee2 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    --offset: 20vw;
    --move-initial: calc(-20% + var(--offset));
    --move-final: calc(-40% + var(--offset));
}

.marquee__inner2 {
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(var(--move-initial), 0, 0);
    animation: marquee 12s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: play;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-family: 'Noctis Bold';
}

.marquee2 span {
    font-size: 5vh;
    padding: 0 2vw;
}

.marquee2:hover .marquee__inner2 {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee2 {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(var(--move-initial), 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(var(--move-final), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="bg33">
        <div class="marquee2" id="showScroll2">
            <div class="marquee__inner2" aria-hidden="true">
                <span>HTML</span>
                <span>CSS</span>
                <span>SASS</span>
                <span>JAVASCRIPT</span>
                <span>JQUERY</span>
                <span>VUE.JS</span>
                <span>PYTHON</span>
                <span>JAVA</span>
                <span>REACT</span>
                <span>GIT</span>
                <span>NPM</span>
                <span>RSTUDIO</span>
                <span>JIRA</span>
                <span>AGILE</span>
                <span>FIGMA</span>
                <span>PS</span>
                <span>ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                <span>BALSAMIQ</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The text doesn't seem to be continuous and it break and starts off again, which is annoying and doesn't show all the text. I want this text to loop over to see appears continuous and full for viewing by the audience. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: https://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/GRJeYOL?editors=1000

Comment: Thank you for providing a snippet but could you check that it shows your problem? The keyframes name does not coincide with the one used for example.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way of doing this - if you know the text will at least cover the viewport width - is to have a second copy. Then you animate by moving the whole thing left by half its width and starting again.

[image]

Here's the altered snippet, note you don't need initial setup conditions to center anything.

```css
  .marquee2 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  --offset: 20vw;
  --move-initial: calc(-20% + var(--offset));
  --move-final: calc(-40% + var(--offset));
}

.marquee__inner2 {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  animation: marquee2 12s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: play;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: 'Noctis Bold';
}

.marquee2 span {
  font-size: 5vh;
  padding: 0 2vw;
}

.marquee2:hover .marquee__inner2 {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg33">
  <div class="marquee2" id="showScroll2">
    <div class="marquee__inner2" aria-hidden="true">
      <span>HTML</span>
      <span>CSS</span>
      <span>SASS</span>
      <span>JAVASCRIPT</span>
      <span>JQUERY</span>
      <span>VUE.JS</span>
      <span>PYTHON</span>
      <span>JAVA</span>
      <span>REACT</span>
      <span>GIT</span>
      <span>NPM</span>
      <span>RSTUDIO</span>
      <span>JIRA</span>
      <span>AGILE</span>
      <span>FIGMA</span>
      <span>PS</span>
      <span>ILLUSTRATOR</span>
      <span>BALSAMIQ</span>
      <span>HTML</span>
      <span>CSS</span>
      <span>SASS</span>
      <span>JAVASCRIPT</span>
      <span>JQUERY</span>
      <span>VUE.JS</span>
      <span>PYTHON</span>
      <span>JAVA</span>
      <span>REACT</span>
      <span>GIT</span>
      <span>NPM</span>
      <span>RSTUDIO</span>
      <span>JIRA</span>
      <span>AGILE</span>
      <span>FIGMA</span>
      <span>PS</span>
      <span>ILLUSTRATOR</span>
      <span>BALSAMIQ</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ADDITION: to go from left to right start at -50% and end at 0.

```
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: how to animate from left to right?

Comment: @MXM_Sam I added this in.