# How to create text carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I want to create an horizontal carousel that has a phrase or several words scrolling end to end of the screen in a loop.

What I've tried is duplicating the phrase in two different divs, to avoid the gap in the animation (otherwise, the phrase goes almost away before it starts from the beginning and looks awful).
The problem (even though I've tried to delay the 2nd animation by half the time of the first one for them not to overlap), depending on the device, the text still overlaps.

How can I create such cacrousel (with or without JS) making sure texts don't overlap? https://tucuerpofit.com/testcarousel/

[image]

Comment: can you share the code you used so that one providing an answer does not start from scratch and out of context

Comment: This is **marquee** do you want that or a carousel?

Comment: @AwatITWork what is the difference?

Comment: Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67684831/943435

Comment: @Roberto that's exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **Bootstrap carousel**, this is much easier and more flexible to work with: here is an example:

Update: The main reason I am telling you to use this, is you have so many ways to design your carousel with all features in Bootstrap, here I just created the simplest one, you can use Left or Right or Click to move to the next slide, also it automatically moves to next slide.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <title>Stack16</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="text-center">Hello, text carousel!</h1>


<div id="textCaro" class="carousel slide mt-1 mb-1" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#textCaro" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#textCaro" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#textCaro" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#textCaro" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner mb-3 mt-3">

        <div class="carousel-item active" >
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="text-center">Text 1</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" >
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="text-center">Text 1</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" >
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="text-center">This is a long text...............</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item" >
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="text-center">Text 1</h4>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#textCaro" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#textCaro" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>

<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

The final result:

[image: Result Image01]

[image: Result Image02]

Comment: is anything supposed to happen there? I used your code and it's just a bunch of buttons and lines of text, no movement or anything related to the carousel / slider

Comment: @DanielRoca if you downloaded the bootstrap correctly you should see something like this, which I will provide the image in my answer.

Comment: I used your example by copy pasting, but nothing is scrolling, what I would expect is the text in a loop moving from one side to another without making it noticeable which is the first or last words, just constantly scrolling, also, I'm using wordpress, if I can avoid bootstrap better

Comment: @DanielRoca, you can control the speed of the carousel, using Javascript or jQuery like this 
**$(document).ready(function(){$("#textCaro").carousel({interval:1500});});**
plus can you show me, your console log when you are doing this

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example, you could customize it as you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Carousel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="carousel" >
        <p>Personal</p>
    </div>
    <style>
        body{
            max-width: 100vw;
            max-height: 100vh;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 0 auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        p{
            margin: 10rem;
            font-size: 2rem;
            font-weight: 900;
            color: white;
        }
        #carousel{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50vh;
            left: 0%;
            animation: mover 5s infinite;
        }
        #carousel>*{
            display: inline-flex;
        }

        #carousel::before{
            color: white;
            content: 'YOUR TEXT';
        }
        
        #carousel::after{
            color: white;
            content: 'YOUR TEXT';
        }

        @keyframes mover {
            0%{
                position: absolute;
                top: 50vh;
                left: 0%;
            }
            100%{
                position: absolute;
                top: 50vh;
                left: 85%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. From one side, there's the horizontal scrollbar growing and shrinking, also the animation starts in the middle, restarts sharply in the middle again and only the first two words are visible (the first two <p>)

Comment: You ask for a carousel , that's it! I said you could customize it, and read better the code because I tryed this code for 4 times and it starts from the left 0 not from the middle. Have a good day